# Validation Summary to show a single message

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my login page, I want to show a single message "Please fill the mandatory fields marked with *" using Validation Summary. But validation summary in actual displays the error message of each textbox. How to fix this issue.

Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the HeaderText property of the ValidationSummary to be your generic message and leave the ErrorMessage of each validation control blank.

Answer (score 0):

Remove error messages from control

```
   <asp:ValidationSummary 
                                  id="valSum" 
                                  DisplayMode="BulletList" 
                                  runat="server"
                                  HeaderText="You must enter a value in marked fields:"
                                  Font-Names="verdana" 
                                  Font-Size="12"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have only this validation message you can use following:

```
<div class="alert alert-error @if (ViewData.ModelState.IsValid){<text>hide</text>}">Please fill the mandatory fields marked with *</div>
```